# HUGE deviation in Sharp IR sensor values if other pins are defined in void setup()

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c++, sketch, ir

I wrote this code for a project -

```
int sensorpin = A5;           
int val = 0;
double avgval = 0;
int E1 = 11;
int brake = 12;
char data = ' ';

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200); 
  pinMode(E1, OUTPUT);   
  pinMode(brake, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(sensorpin, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{

  if (Serial.available()>0){
      data = Serial.read();
    }

  val = analogRead(sensorpin);   
  avgval = average(val);
  double volt = (avgval*5)/1023;
  Serial.println (avgval);
  Serial.println(volt);            
  delay(1000);   

  if (data == 'G'){
    analogWrite(E1, 255);
    digitalWrite(brake, LOW);
  }

  if( volt > 1.5 && volt < 1.75 ){
    digitalWrite(brake, HIGH);
  }
}

double average(double adc){
  int n = 1;
  double avg = 0.00, sum = 0.00;
  while(n<=23){
    sum = sum + adc;
    avg = sum/25;
    n++;
  }
  return avg;
}
```

The code works fine, except for the fact that the Sharp IR sensor (GP2Y0A710K0F) outputs values which are wrong (by a HUGE distance), **ONLY** if in the `void setup()` function, the commands -

```
pinMode(E1, OUTPUT);  
pinMode(brake, OUTPUT);
```

are left *uncommented*. If I comment the above two statements, the sketch works fine.

What on earth is wrong here? I can't make out anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why commenting out those two lines makes a difference.  I think we need to see a schematic to resolve this.

However...

You do not use "pinMode" to setup an analog input!

Look at the examples on the ["analogRead" page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogRead).  Notice there is no setup needed for the analog pin.  Just call "analogRead" like you are doing and everything should be fine.

Comment: And that was it! Removing the line `pinMode(sensorpin, A5)` and *uncommenting* the two lines solved my problem. Getting the expected readings now. Thanks very much! That was something I should have noticed long ago.